# Mysqli error 1064 CREATE TABLE

Tags: php, mysqli

This is working:

```
$req = $mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$tableprefix."admin (
            ID_ADMIN INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            login VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            password VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            mail VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY(ID_ADMIN))");
```

This is not working:

```
$req2 = $mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$tableprefix."pages (
            ID_PAGE INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            title VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            content TEXT,
            order INT NOT NULL,
            status INT NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY(ID_PAGE))");
```

Anybody can help me? Thank you

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 4):

`ORDER` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql so you would need to enclose it in backticks:

```
`order` INT NOT NULL,
```

or use a different name (that's what I would do).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't name a column in the table "order" ... it's a reserved word.  Call it something else, like p_order, or something.  It will only get more confusing later on, especially if you ever want to ORDER by it.